# Using Http module for authorization AuthorizeRequest or BeginRequest

Tags: .net, asp.net, authorization, httpmodule

I have a wap site with susciription and I want to check if users are authorized to see some pages. I have decided to use http module. 
Should I use  **AuthorizeRequest** or **BeginRequest** to check the users status? and why?

Answer (score 1):

You obviously should handle **AuthorizeRequest** event since you need to know who is the user (authentication must have been processed).

Answer (score 0):

You really have not given enough information to garner an authoritative answer but I can provide a bit of information to get you started on refining your question.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39026/Exploring-Web-config-system-web-httpModules.aspx

Some relevant information would be a description of your authentication strategy.

Update your question and leave me a comment and I will get right back to you.

Comment: Hi,
I'm trying to implement something like  servlet filter for JSF. in JSF
I have used <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> to run the request for once per request.